# Minimum permission (below Full Control ) to allow a user to view all the responses inside a SharePoint survey

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, survey, survey-list, item-level-permissions

We have a Survey inside SharePoint communication online site, and we set that users can view and edit their own responses ONLY as follow:-

[image]

but in our case we want 2 users to be able to view all the responses, i tried to grant them Edit but still they can view only their own responses,, so my question is what is the minimum permission (below Full Control) required to be able to view all responses? can we create a custom permission level for this, and what we need to specify exactly ?

Comment: did you try both "Read all responses" and Create and Edit all Responses?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP is i set these, then all users can view all responses, while i only want 2 users to be able to view all responses..

Answer (score 0):

Create two views - 1) View All Response and 2) Response created or Modified by the user.

Create a SharePoint access group with full control and add those users there who can access the "View All Response" view - then assign that group permission in "View All Response "

And for "Response created or Modified by the user" view apply the filter on created By or Modified By equal to [Me]